# Is it possible to register with socialite and add more required data to user?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth, single-page-application, laravel-socialite

I want to create a web app using Laravel and I want to use Socialite to register users using Gmail, but I want to know instead of creating a user record in the callback, I want to give a sign to the frontend (Vuejs) and let it view a form where user should complete his information then submit the data.

If its not an SPA I would say I have to save user data in the callback in the session then return a view and fill other info ...etc, but in my case its SPA and I don't have session so whats the solution for this problem ?

Comment: if javascript wasn't involved you could create the user with what socialite gives you back but mark the account as not complete, then have a middleware that checks if the account is complete, if not send to a form to finish filling in data, mark as complete and move on ... basically create a walled garden

Comment: This is gonna be my last solution, before that I will try to find a way to not create the user at all !

Comment: If I saved the full parameters of the callback URL then send them to another route, will I be able to get the Socialite user ?

Comment: if you store the token you get from that callback, then you should be able to retrieve that same information later from the provider with something like `userFromToken` or `userFromTokenAndSecret` I would think